# Cannot find module 'next/dist/lib/metadata/types/metadata-interface.js' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: next.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  output: "export",
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

```
../out/types/app/page.ts:3:40
Type error: Cannot find module 'next/dist/lib/metadata/types/metadata-interface.js' or its corresponding type declarations.

  1 | // File: E:\dev-App\tauri\edit-json-menu\app\page.tsx
  2 | import * as entry from '../../../edit-json-menu/app/page.js'
> 3 | import type { ResolvingMetadata } from 'next/dist/lib/metadata/types/metadata-interface.js'
    |                                        ^
  4 |
  5 | type TEntry = typeof import('../../../edit-json-menu/app/page.js')
  6 |
```

After running the pnpm run build, this issue occurred during the nextjs build process

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please share the relevant part of the code that causes this error.

Comment: Seeing the same, on Next 14.0.3 with a pretty barebones project. (Using the App Router.) Did you ever sort this out?